# Need advice re chance of damage to a stainless steel tray in a very hot oven

Tags: equipment, temperature, cleaning, stainless-steel

I need to heat a clean stainless steel tray to the temperature of boiling water. Would the self-cleaning cycle of the oven damage my tray in any way?

Comment: Last I heard the self cleaning cycle of most electric ovens is hotter than the highest temperature you can set it to. *SIGNIFICANTLY* hotter than you need to boil water (212F & 100C). And they usually lock the door till the cleaning cycle is done so 500F (or more) for several hours!

Answer (score 4):

The temperature of boiling water is 100° Celsius or 212° Fahrenheit. This is considerably colder than the self-cleaning cycle in your oven. It would be perfectly sufficient to set the oven temperature to about 120°C/240°F to heat the tray. It would not take long to reach the desired temperature for the tray at those lower temperatures since metals conduct heat well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about damage at all.

Comment: Per our Help Center answers that offer a viable alternative are fine. >>The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”.<<

Answer (score 1):

If it is non-magnetic (304) it could be sensitized at about 1100 F (very dim red heat) which would reduce corrosion resistance to boiling brine. If it is magnetic (410), I can't imagine you could hurt it in the oven or surface burners. It could ruin bakelite handles. So there is no way you can damage any stainless in a home oven .

Comment: This sounds plausible for a single lump of steel. In the kitchen, you can have all kinds of complications - a thin tray becoming permanently bent due to uneven heating, or some decoration (beyond the bakelite handles you mention) suffering, or even having a layered item where it is not steel through and through (admittedly, this is usually seen in pans, rather uncommon in trays). Just because the steel can take it, I wouldn't be quick to promise that a random kitchen item "made of steel" can.

Comment: Cladding is tolerant ; We tested some by heating to 500 F and blast cooling with saturated steam , thousands of cycles . It was roughly an inch thick ( steel with stainless cladding ). Many refinery and chemical plant vessels are clad).